# How do I customize the auto-inserted XML-comments in C#/VS2010 without external tools

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xml-documentation

If you type "///" VS2010 inserts an xml-doc block. However, there seems no way to customize the xml-doc templates which get inserted. I only found a way doing it for VB.NET or with external tools like GhostDoc.

Is there a way to do it without external tools?

Answer (score 4):

[MSDN to the rescue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx)

Comment: I'm 95% sure that they both just use template documents.  You can actually modify your class template to have a special header or footer (think copyright) and XML Docs are just a similar type of template

Comment: I was thinking about the fact that the file name is VB*.xml

Comment: Right, I would guess there is a parallel file for C#?  Not 100% sure though.

Comment: Im pretty sure it does not work for C#. I tested it with a file called _CSharpXmlDoc.xml_ and it did not work. The whole _keyword_ -> _template_ mapping does not make sense in every case in C#.For instance, you do not have the equivalent to the _function_ keyword in VB.NET in C#.